# Reference an interface name without the class name

Tags: c#, interface, namespaces

This is probalby really simple and I have just looked at it too long. In my project I have a Contracts.cs with the following code:

```
namespace RC.Common.Core.ProcessPlugin
{
    public class Contracts
    {
        public interface IProcessPlugin
        {
            void RunProcess(int jobID);
        }

        public interface IProcessMetaData
        {
            string Process { get; }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have PluginProcessFactory.cs with this as some of its code:

```
namespace RC.Common.Core.ProcessPlugin
{
    public class PluginProcessFactory
    {
        [ImportMany]
        IEnumerable<Lazy<Contracts.IProcessPlugin, Contracts.IProcessMetaData>> processes;

        // more code
    }
}
```

How can I get it so that the references to the interfaces in the IEnumerable don't contain the class reference in the name?  So it looks like this:

```
        IEnumerable<Lazy<IProcessPlugin, IProcessMetaData>> processes;
```

Comment: move the interfaces out of the class.

Comment: @Sadek can't agree with you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the interfaces inside of a class:

```
namespace RC.Common.Core.ProcessPlugin
{
    // Place directly in namespace
    // public class Contracts
    // {
        public interface IProcessPlugin
        {
            void RunProcess(int jobID);
        }

        public interface IProcessMetaData
        {
            string Process { get; }
        }
    // }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something simple, just was looking at it to long and missing the obvious.